# python keras use calculate the hamming loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I want to calculate the hamming loss for multilabel classification. I defined some custom metrics of the keras model as follows:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy',recall_m,precision_m,custom_f1,HAMMING_LOSS])
```

Is it possible to use sklearn.metrics?

```
from sklearn.metrics import hamming_loss
def HAMMING_LOSS(y_true, y_pred):    
  return hamming_loss(y_true, y_pred)
```

I can't quite make it work
Is there another way ?
thanks

UPDATE i also tried a cutom hamming loss function and its still not working

```
def hamming_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize=True, sample_weight=None):
    acc_list = []
    for i in range(y_true.shape[0]):
        set_true = set( np.where(y_true[i])[0] )
        set_pred = set( np.where(y_pred[i])[0] )
        #print('\nset_true: {0}'.format(set_true))
        #print('set_pred: {0}'.format(set_pred))
        tmp_a = None
        if len(set_true) == 0 and len(set_pred) == 0:
            tmp_a = 1
        else:
            tmp_a = len(set_true.intersection(set_pred))/\
                    float( len(set_true.union(set_pred)) )
        #print('tmp_a: {0}'.format(tmp_a))
        acc_list.append(tmp_a)
    return np.mean(acc_list[2])
```

i got the error

```
TypeError: in user code:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
<ipython-input-34-cf5b14c1e9f9>:160 hamming_score  *
    for i in range(y_true.shape[0]):
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/py_builtins.py:353 range_  **
    return _py_range(start_or_stop, stop, step)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/py_builtins.py:378 _py_range
    return range(start_or_stop)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: could you please report the last part of your network, in order that I can build the hamming loss compatible with keras

Comment: hi @MarcoCerliani the last part of the model as follow 
deep_inputs = Input(shape=(maxlen,))
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 100,  trainable=False)(deep_inputs)
LSTM_Layer_1 = LSTM(128)(embedding_layer)
dense_layer_1 = Dense(6, activation='sigmoid')(LSTM_Layer_1)#softplus,selu,
model = Model(inputs=deep_inputs, outputs=dense_layer_1)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy',recall_m,precision_m,custom_f1,hamming_score])

Comment: what error do you get from this `model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy',recall_m,precision_m,custom_f1, hamming_loss])`, note the lowercase

Comment: hi @Kenan i got the error 
at the fit function after the compile 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-cf5b14c1e9f9> in <module>()
    206 print(model.metrics_names)
    207 
--> 208 history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=1, verbose=1, validation_split=0.3)
    209 score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
    210

Comment: based on your error message it looks like `y_true is None` in your custom `hamming_score` function

Comment: that's why i did something like this
def hl(y_true, y_pred):
  print (y_true)
  print (y_pred)
  return 1
and call it in the metrics
and it prints both y_true and y_pred